# Can not use HttpClient from Asp MVC 6 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I try to write simple code:

```cs
 public async Task<string> GetData(String labelName)
    {           
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var uri = new Uri(@"https://example.com/over/search_field?=search_label=" + labelName);

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var textResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return textResult;
        }
    }
```

At project.json:

```json
 {
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
 "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
 "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
 "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",

 "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
 "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
 "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-beta8",
 "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.22"
  },      
 "frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin": "5.2.3",
      "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23409"


   },
   "frameworkAssemblies": {
     "System.Net": "4.0.0.0",
     "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0"
   }
 },
 "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

But, when i try to build code i get error:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can you help me? How to fix this error?
I use VS 2015 and ASP MVC 6 Web API.
Thank you!

Comment: Try moving `"dependencies"` outside of the `"frameworks"`. I assume your application could not be compiled when targeting `dnxcore50`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me. I added `System.Net.Http` to the `dependencies` section and built the project (thus restored this new dependency in both `DNX 4.5.1` and `DNX Core 5.0`)

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    // Removed some dependencies for saving space:)
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23409"
},
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {}
},
```

Verified in the below runtimes and it works fine.

- coreclr - X86 - 1.0.0-rc1-update1
- coreclr - X64 - 1.0.0-rc1-update1
- clr - X86 - 1.0.0-rc1-update1
- clr - X64 - 1.0.0-rc1-update1

Also, you need to make sure that you have the `using` directive which imports the System.Net.Http namespace in the class file where you have your `GetData` method.

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

Comment: Thank you - using rc1-update1 x64 and solved my issue.